# Convolution of h(n) & x(n)

Tags: convolution, homework

can anyone please help me with finding Convolution for following problem .....

1) $h(n) = \delta[\sin(1 + |n|)]\quad \text{and}\quad x(n) = \sin(n^2)$

2) $h(n) = \delta[\sin(2\pi n/N)] \quad \text{and}\quad x(n) = n^2$ where $N$ is odd.

Comment: It would help if you showed us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

I assume that $n$ is an integer and that we're talking about discrete-time signals. You need to simplify the expressions for $h(n)$ by noting that $\delta(n)=1$ for $n=0$ and zero otherwise. So, for which values of $n$ does $\sin(1+|n|)$ equal zero, and for which values of $n$ does $\sin(2\pi n/N)$ equal zero?

Comment: 1+|n| never becomes equal to k*pi. does this mean convolution result is zero ?

Comment: for sin(2*pi*n/N), n must be equal to kN/2 for it to become zero... so what limits must be put in convolution sum ?

Comment: @SanilTalaulikar: You're right about the first one. If the problem is really as you've put it in the question then $h(n)=0$ and the result is indeed zero. For the second one, note that $N$ is odd, so $kN/2$ is not an integer. This means that $n=kN$ and you have an impulse comb: $h(n)=\sum_k\delta(n-kN)$.